# Extension that allows redirect after file download

Tags: extension-request

I need an extension that manages files, creates a download link for these files on the website and redirects the client to another page after the download button was clicked.

Phoca Download is unfortunately [not providing this feature.](http://www.phoca.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=25415)

Please let me know if you got experience with an extension that has this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A download button typically opens another tab to the download, if you need a redirect afterwords you can do a little JS to assist with that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('CLASS OR ID OF BUTTON LINK').on('click',function(){
      window.location.href = 'PAGE TO GO TO AFTER BUTTON IS CLICKED';
   });
});
```

This should not disturb the functionality of the download link (although depending on how it works it may need adjustment). It should redirect the user right after it is clicked.

You can add this to your templates `index.php` file within a script tag in the head of the page. You can also use some PHP to adjust the page it will go too. I do not know much about what your trying to do but this could give you a head start.

Extensions do not always do exactly what you want, sometimes it can be easier to just extend it yourself. Joomla provides template overrides to make this easier as well.